# SQL Server delete a value on ID column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete, auto-increment, window-functions

In my database there is a column for `ID` where is set to "auto incremental"

So when I delete a row where `ID = 2` for example and insert a new row ID takes value of 3.

The question is how to set ID return to 2 and not 3 on action Delete?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Comment: An auto-increment value always increment, even if you delete rows.

Comment: Thanks for replying
So there is no other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why would it actually be a problem to have gaps in an auto-incremented column?

Comment: The reason why if i had to display this column in my website would it be suitable to have gaps displayed?

Comment: The auto increment column is known as a surrogate key. Its purpose is to be uniquely identifiable, and needs to work reliably across transactions which may or may not rollback. The behaviour you describe would be impossible in some situations. It also violates the premise that a column serves one purpose and one purpose alone. As you want a user friendly sequential number for presentation, you should use a new column, Not reuse an existing one. Possibly using ROW_NUMBER() or similar. Either way, however, this strongly smells like a sql anti pattern. You're probably solving the wrong problem.

Comment: `"So there is no other way to solve this problem?"` _What problem?_ This is how databases work. It's actually much better to preserve the missing space. This helps with a number of situations. For example, if someone had bookmarked an old URL that looks up a record by ID, you don't want them to see the wrong data.

Answer (score 1):

As most other auto-increment implementations in other databases, SQL Server's identity columns does not offer any option to "fill the gaps" left when numbers are wasted (which may happen not only when rows are deleted,  but also possibly when a transaction is rolled back or when the server restarts).

This is clearly specified [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The identity property on a column does not guarantee the following:
>
> [...]
>
> **Reuse of values** - For a given identity property with specific seed/increment, the identity values are not reused by the engine.

If, for displaying purpose, you want a constantly increasing value that resets when rows are deleted, you can use `row_number()` in a `select` query:

```
select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) new_id
from mytable t
```

If you are going to use that on a regular bases, you can create a view, that you can then query instead of the original table:

```
create view myview as
select t.*, row_number() over(order by id) new_id
from mytable t;

select * from myview;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CHEKIDENT database console command to change the identity value of the table after you delete, although you should use this only if you are deleting the last record.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('YourTable', RESEED, 2)
```

Comment: You'd be safer just issuing an UPDATE rather than the DELETE. At least you can do That in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually want to do this.   You may not see it now but having an identity column that will always identify the row that was deleted is a good thing.

If you need a column to behave a different way just create a new column and apply business rules to have it work the way you want.

Call it ID_NOGAP and then make sure that there are never gaps.  You can do this in the data access layer or with triggers on the DB (not recommended.)